# Exercise 1.8 (b) ,(d) and (e) in Haynes Miller's Lectures on Algebraic Topology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

When I try to do the Exercise 1.8 in Haynes Miller's book, I found that I do not really need the clue he provided. Am I wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJb2Z.png)

For example, in question (b), I do not need the identity $d^i d^j = d^{j+1}d^i$ for $i<j$ to prove the uniqueness. Because when I find out that $j_i$'s are just ones in $([n] \setminus \textrm{Im}\phi)$, then $\phi$ has been determined by this information ($\phi$ is an order-preserving injection, it is determined by its range.)